# Qt resources not displaying when building with cmake (windows)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, resources

I have a Visual Studio Qt solution that I am moving to Cmake. 
Everything is compiling and working fine, except all icons (.png) that I have in *.qrc file are not displayed at all.
My `CMakeLists.txt` is standard for a Qt project:

```
...

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES ...)
set(HEADER_FILES ...)
set(UI_FILES ...)
set(RESOURCE_FILES resources/res.qrc)
add_executable(project WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${UI_FILES} ${RESOURCE_FILES})

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE Qt5::Core etc...)
```

I think that all icons are in fact embedded into .exe, because:
1. If I remove all paths from the `qrc` file and recompile, the .exe size is decreased by the icons size
2. I checked the `qrc_*.cpp` generated by `AUTORCC` and all the images are there.

But when I am iterating over all my resources using this code snippet

```cpp
QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```

the icons are NOT there.

I have tried an alternative approach with `qt5_add_resources()` instead of `AUTORCC` and the result is the same.
I also have all the `iconengines`, `imageformats`, `platforms`, `styles` folders on the same path as .exe.

### Edit:

Added the whole `Cmake` part of the project to [github](https://github.com/estw272/cmake-so).

Comment: Are you sure you may iterate over resources with a directory iterator? Did you try to refer to a particular icon?

Comment: @vahancho I am sure, it's working when compiling as Visual Studio solution. And I have tried loading specific resource and checking its height, it's always 0.

Comment: You are most likely missing a call to `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(res)` for some reason. You shouldn't though, as the equivalent code is at the bottom of the generated cpp file. So unless you shot your static initializers somehow, that should never go missing.

Comment: @Ext3h Tried adding this to code, unfortunately nothing changed. I wonder if there is anything else that can be done to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Then you can only try using debug build of Qt, and check for any possible warning emitted by Qt. Repectively debug into Qt itself. If that call worked (compiled), than it was not a linker issues, and the resources together the loading code are indeed properly part of the executable

Comment: Are qrc_*.cpp files part of your Visual Studio solution?

Comment: Also, what version of CMake are you using?

Comment: @jpo38 tried 3.16 and 3.17. Do you mean if i include qrc_*.cpp files into `add_executable`? No, I think `AUTORCC` is doing that and I am only supposed to include the main resource `resource.qrc` file?

Comment: You are right. But my question is do you actually see them in the solution explorer after you open it with Visual Studio? Because if you don't see them, it means they will not be compiled so it's not surprising resources are not available at runtime.

Comment: @jpo38 Hm no, I don't see it. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: It's weird, if they don't appear in the solution, why do you see "If I remove all paths from the qrc file and recompile, the .exe size is decreased by the icons size"? Can you check in the build log if those qrc_*.cpp files are compiled or not? You can also edit one of those file manually with an invalid c++ syntax and see if compilation fails, if it doesn't, it means the file is actually not compiled by Visual Studio.

Comment: @jpo38 I edited qrc_radmin.cpp and got an error `[3/4] Building CXX object apps\radmin\CMakeFiles\radmin.dir\radmin_autogen\3YJK5W5UP7\qrc_radmin.cpp.obj
FAILED: apps/radmin/CMakeFiles/radmin.dir/radmin_autogen/3YJK5W5UP7/qrc_radmin.cpp.obj ` so it seems that it's compiling.

Comment: @jpo38 This is from build.ninja: `build cmake_object_order_depends_target_radmin: phony || apps\radmin\radmin_autogen apps\radmin\radmin_autogen\3YJK5W5UP7\qrc_radmin.cpp cmake_object_order_depends_target_radmin_version`

Comment: All this is wierd, are you sure your resources are loaded correctly? Have you tried to call `Q_INIT_RESOURCE()` does exactly the same code work when not using `CMAKE_AUTORCC` but `QT5_ADD_RESOURCES`?

Comment: @jpo38 Yeah, every time I use cmake I get these bugs in most unexpected places. I am calling `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` and `AUTORCC` and `qt5_add_resources` behave identically. Not sure what you mean by resources loading correctly, I guess not since they don't display.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in "initializer" constructor in a qrc_*.cpp file? Is it reached when you app loads?

Comment: @jpo38 Ok, here's the twist. When I run my app from clion it shows the images. If I copy the exe to a folder with *.dll etc it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the discussion we had in your post comment, `CMake` works as expected and the resources are loaded into your application.

As you mentioned "When I run my app from clion it shows the images. If I copy the exe to a folder with *.dll etc it doesn't.", so either:

- Some files are missing when you copy them, you should try to use `windeployqt` to correctly copy what's needed at runtime
- Or the problem comes from the way the qrc is neing loaded, then, I suggest that you debug the content of qrc_*.cpp files (your can debug it after you copied it outside clion) and see why it fails to load the resource

Anyway this looks more like a deployment issue than a configuration/compilation issue.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for me in a similar situation was adding a line into CMake like this:

```
QT6_ADD_RESOURCES(PROJECT_RESOURCES ${RESOURCE_FILES})
```

So instead of plugging ${RESOURCE_FILES} into add_executable directly, you plug into QT6_ADD_RESOURCES first, and then you put PROJECTS_RESOURCES variable into add_executable.
As a result, you SHOULD see the qrc_res.cpp file in VS source files.
The full code snippet:

```
set(RESOURCE_FILES resources/res.qrc)
QT6_ADD_RESOURCES(PROJECT_RESOURCES ${RESOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES} ${UI_FILES} ${PROJECT_RESOURCES})
```

Hope this helps